# Hibernate Query - Get latest versions by timestamp?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, hql

I have a database that is being used as a sort of version control system. That is, instead of ever updating any rows, I add a new row with the same information. Each row also contains a `version` column that is a date timestamp, so the only difference is the new row will have a more recent timestamp.

What I'm having trouble with is writing an efficient hibernate query to return the latest version of these rows. For the sake of example, these are rows in a table called `Product`, the timestamped column is `version`. There are multiple versions of multiple products in the table. So there may be multiple versions (rows) of ProductA, multiple versions of ProductB, etc. And I would like to grab the latest version of each.

Can I do this in just a single hibernate query?

```
session.createQuery("select product from Product product where...?");
```

Or would this require some intermediate steps?

Comment: You have multiple products, how are they identified? Is this product identifier constant, or can it change?

Comment: Each product has a Long value identifier that is constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this, each product needs some kind of identifier. Since there can be multiple versions, we need to know "what is a product" I'm assuming `product.id` is out, as this is probably a surrogate key. I'll choose `product.name` for sake of example.

Here's a single query to retrieve the latest version of each product:

```
select p1 from Product p1 where
  p1.timestamp >= all (
     select p2.timestamp from Product p2 where
      p2.name=p1.name
  )
```

(My HQL is a bit rusty, but I hope you get the gist.)

The trick is the self join between like products of differing timestamps. `p1` products are more recently modified than `p2`. To find the most recent `p1`, we find rows where there are no `p2` values - i.e. there are no product more recent than  `p1`.

EDIT: I've revised the query - I'd saw someone used the "on" syntax in a forum post recently, but I now remember that that is not valid HQL. Sorry about that - I don't have a system available to test on. It now uses a correlated subquery that functions the same as the JOIN.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately I'm having a hell of a time converting this into usable HQL. I'm generally opposed to asking for the answer to be directly handed to me, but writing queries is definitely not my area. If anybody could help clear this up I would sincerely appreciate it.

Comment: Was about to comment the previous answer to say that you need an association in HQL for out join. But the update is correct, this new query works.

Comment: mdma - thank you so much for both a wonderful answer and a username that's just as great ;)

Pascal Thivent, thanks for the confirmation.

This has been an incredibly helpful answer all around. Cheers!

Comment: Hehe! You're welcome. The username comes from my days at uni - it was given to me by the sysadmins, but I guess they weren't aware of what they were dishng out ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To find the latest version of a particular product:

```
select product where ... order by version DESC
```

put a compound key with the version too.

To find the latest version of all products, you need two queries (or a subquery):

```
Insert into TMP (id, version) select (id, max(version)) from product group by id);
select P.* Product P, TMP where TMP.ID = P.ID
```

Comment: I think the OP want's the latest version of all products, this gives all versions ordered newest first. E.g. if there were 5 copies of product A, and one of B, and all of A were modified more recently than B, then you would get 5 instances of A followed by B. I think the OP wants just one instance of A and one row of B - the latest one in both cases.

Comment: If he is querying for just one product, run the query and select the first row.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the question being asked. Quote: "And I would like to grab the latest version of each."