# How to select the most recent rows from oracle using hibernate?

Tags: sql, hibernate

lets say i have a table (Product) consisting of 4 columns, the last_update is a DATE field.

```
id       prod_id       last_update      status
1          100          7/8/2014        built 
2          100          9/10/2014       in process
3          210          7/8/2014        in process 
4          210          9/10/2014       built
```

is it possible to write a query in hibernate to select the last updated rows for each product? in this case id 2 and 4?

appreciate your answer as always

Comment: if `last_update` column is of type `date` then it can b easily done with `order by` if its of type varchar try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545888/sql-order-by-date-problem

Comment: @exexzian yes but that is not what i asked

Comment: ohh I completely misread your question

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select *
from my_table t1
where last_update = (select max(last_update) from my_table t2 where t1.prod_id = t2.prod_id;
```

Hibernate specific:
From a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751941/hibernate-query-get-latest-versions-by-timestamp):

```
select p1 from my_table t1 where
  t1.last_update = max (
     select t2.last_update from my_table t2 where
      t2.prod_id=t1.prod_id
  )
```

Comment: @nightograph  Sorry.  Didn't realize hibernate was so different from actual sql.

Comment: no problem, do you know how i can get partial result from your sql query?

Comment: By partial results do you mean the first x rows or something?